# Update multiple documents in MongoDB (rmongodb)

Tags: r, mongodb, crud, rmongodb, database

I stumbled upon some issues regarding the function handling updates (`mongo.update()`).

### Disclaimer

As I'm still in the middle of getting familiar with both [MongoDB](http://www.mongodb.org/) and the [rmongodb](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rmongodb/index.html) package, the illustrated issues might all very well be due to my lack of knowledge ;-)

### Preparations

**Ensuring that package is loaded**

```
pkg <- "rmongodb"
lib <- file.path(R.home(), "library")
if (!suppressWarnings(require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE))) {
    install.packages(pkg, lib=lib)
    require(pkg, lib.loc=lib, character.only=TRUE)
}
```

**Global variables**

```
db      <- "__test"
ns.0    <- "user"
ns      <- paste(db, ns.0, sep=".")
con     <- mongo.create(db=db)
```

### Creating the initial state of the DB

**Ensure emtpy DB**

```
mongo.remove(mongo=con, ns=ns, 
    criteria=mongo.bson.from.list(lst=list(namefirst="John")))
```

**Insert document**

```
fields      <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Doe")
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=b)
if (is.null(mongo.find.one(mong=con, ns=ns, query=b))) {
    stop("Something went wrong")
}
```

**Update/upsert a document**

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Smith")
fields      <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Smith", age=30)
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=crit, objNew=b, 
    flags=mongo.update.upsert)
if (is.null(mongo.find.one(mong=con, ns=ns, query=b))) {
    stop("Something went wrong")
}
```

**List available docs**

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John")
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
cursor      <- mongo.find(mongo=con, ns=ns, query=crit)
out         <- NULL
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor=cursor)) {
    bson <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor=cursor)    
    out <- c(out, list(bson))
}
> out
[[1]]
    _id : 7      50f484fe3c3b8b8e3daa72e0
    namefirst : 2    John
    namelast : 2     Doe

[[2]]
    _id : 7      50f484ff3c3b8b8e3daa72e1
    namefirst : 2    John
    namelast : 2     Smith
    age : 1      30.000000
```

At this point, there are two docs in the collection which is what we'd expect.

### Issue #1: update with default flag value (`0`)

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John")
fields      <- list(age=99)
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=crit, objNew=b)
cursor      <- mongo.find(mongo=con, ns=ns, query=crit)
out         <- NULL
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor=cursor)) {
    bson <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor=cursor)
    out <- c(out, list(mongo.bson.to.list(bson)))
}
if (out[[1]]$age != 99) {
    stop("Something went wrong")
}
> out
[[1]]
[[1]]$`_id`
{ $oid : "50f484ff3c3b8b8e3daa72e1" }

[[1]]$namefirst
[1] "John"

[[1]]$namelast
[1] "Smith"

[[1]]$age
[1] 30
```

After performing the update, there's only one document left.

### Issue #2: update with "multi" flag value (`2`)

Start over from scratch as previous update seems to have corrupted the DB:

**Ensure empty DB**

```
mongo.remove(mongo=con, ns=ns, 
    criteria=mongo.bson.from.list(lst=list(namefirst="John")))
```

**Insert document**

```
fields      <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Doe")
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
mongo.insert(mongo=con, ns=ns, b=b)
if (is.null(mongo.find.one(mong=con, ns=ns, query=b))) {
    stop("Something went wrong")
}
```

**Update/upsert document**

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Smith")
fields      <- list(namefirst="John", namelast="Smith", age=30)
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=crit, objNew=b, 
    flags=mongo.update.upsert)
if (is.null(mongo.find.one(mong=con, ns=ns, query=b))) {
    stop("Something went wrong")
}
```

Trying to update multiple documents. What I'm after here is to change the value for `age` to `99` in both collections

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John")
fields      <- list(age=99)
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=fields)
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=crit, objNew=b, 
    flags=mongo.update.multi)
cursor      <- mongo.find(mongo=con, ns=ns, query=crit)
out         <- NULL
while (mongo.cursor.next(cursor=cursor)) {
    bson <- mongo.cursor.value(cursor=cursor)
    out <- c(out, list(mongo.bson.to.list(bson)))
}
```

**Investigating the current DB state**

```
> out
[[1]]
[[1]]$`_id`
{ $oid : "50f485cd3c3b8b8e3daa72e2" }

[[1]]$namefirst
[1] "John"

[[1]]$namelast
[1] "Doe"


[[2]]
[[2]]$`_id`
{ $oid : "50f485ce3c3b8b8e3daa72e3" }

[[2]]$namefirst
[1] "John"

[[2]]$namelast
[1] "Smith"

[[2]]$age
[1] 30

> sapply(out, function(ii) ii$age)
[[1]]
NULL

[[2]]
[3] 30
```

I would expect both docs to have `age = 99`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In both "potential bugs", you are updating the record to one that contains only the age field.  Your records still exist, but they have no namefirst fields (or any other field besides age and _id)  to match the later query.  mongo.update() normally replaces the entire document, not selected fields.  Your 2nd example could be coded like this:

```
criteria    <- list(namefirst="John")
fields      <- list(age=99)
b           <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=list('$set'=fields))
crit        <- mongo.bson.from.list(lst=criteria)
mongo.update(mongo=con, ns=ns, criteria=crit, objNew=b, 
    flags=mongo.update.multi)
```

to set only desired fields.  See http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/update for more information.

Btw, though your example is very clear, you may write this much more succinctly as:

```
mongo.update(con, ns, list(namefirst="John"),
                      list('$set'=list(age=99)), mongo.update.multi)
```

Comment: Great, thanks a lot - again something learned! Didn't mean to sound disrespectful or anything with labeling the whole thing "possible bugs" ;-) Thanks for taking the time!

Comment: You are welcome...  No problem.  Sorry, I couldn't resist the sarcastic quotes around 'potential bugs' :)

Comment: Just wanted to say +1, this saved the day. I couldnt for the life of me figure out how to update anything until your answer. Complex examples are sparse online for certain mongo related tasks. Thanks again.